# Mixing C and assembly and its impact on registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Consider the following C and (ARM) assembly snippet, which is to be compiled with GCC:

```c
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "vldmia.64 %[data_addr]!, {d0-d1}\n\t"
        "vmov.f32 q12, #0.0\n\t"
        : [data_addr] "+r" (data_addr)
        : : "q0", "q12");

for(int n=0; n<10; ++n){
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "vadd.f32 q12, q12, q0\n\t"
            "vldmia.64 %[data_addr]!, {d0-d1}\n\t"
            : [data_addr] "+r" (data_addr),
            :: "q0", "q12");
}
```

In this example, I am initialising some SIMD registers outside the loop and then having C handle the loop logic, with those initialised registers being used inside the loop.

This works in some test code, but I'm concerned of the risk of the compiler clobbering the registers between snippets. Is there any way of ensuring this doesn't happen? Can I infer any assurances about the type of registers that are going to be used in a snippet (in this case, that no SIMD registers will be clobbered)?

Comment: If the code is this simple, why not make it all asm? Or is it just an example?

Comment: It's a simplified example, but certainly I could make it all asm. The reservation is simply that it makes the whole code harder to read and modify and the compiler is very good at outputting loops.

Comment: There is no guarantee the compiler will preserve the registers in C code. Make it a **single** statement. And add a memory clobber.

Comment: You are prudent to consider that possibility.  The safest alternative is to assume nothing about register use between *or around* your assembly snippets.  Not only may C code between the assembly segments mess with the registers, but your manipulation of the registers could also trample on GCC's register usage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was expecting as much. The latter case I would expect should be dealt with by the clobber list, but there is no equivalent the other way. It would be nice to have a register protection mode (which would also imply I know what I'm doing and I understand this may make everything run very slowly if I cock it up)

Comment: There's some good stuff in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) about inline asm.  e.g. using output operands that the C code never touches is a good way to let gcc choose which scratch registers, instead of hard-coding some.  And @Olaf: This could avoid using a memory clobber if the code used a memory operand rather than asking for the address in a register.  Then the compiler would know *which* memory was touched.  IIRC, there's a constraint to ask for a post-incremented addressing mode.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there's not a way to do this in gcc; clobbers only guarantee that registers will be preserved around the asm call. If you need to ensure that the registers are saved between two asm sections, you will need to store them to memory in the first, and reload in the second.

Comment: Clearly that's suboptimal when I'm at the point of writing hand crafted assembly!

Comment: Note that the compiler may very well optimize the store and the reload away, since it has all the required information. Also, for SIMD stuff, you might want to look at builtin vector support.

Comment: I had an idea that I could declare the registers to C using the SIMD intrinsics, but there are issues with certain instructions (that can't be accessed through the intrinsics, like vector multiply with scalar), that require a subset of the registers to be used.

Comment: It may be suboptimal for your purposes, but it is unfortunately the truth. As Jester said, it's possible the compiler can do something with this anyway. Sorry I can't give you the answer that you want, but there just isn't a way to do it in gcc or clang.

Comment: @Jester Does the building vector support offer more than intrinsics? I initially coded the solution with intrinsics, but certain instructions are inaccessible. Specifically vector multiply by a scalar (VMLA with a scalar second argument).

Comment: The vector support version generated vdup+vmul for me, possibly some arch specific option should be set to get vmla?

Comment: Not "to memory", but "to output operands".  You can and should use constraints like `"rm"` if appropriate to let the compiler choose, or just `"r"` on a load/store machine where memory operands can't be used with most instructions.  Anyway, this lets the compiler store if it wants to.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your crucial points. I've posted a solution that in my test code works, and afaict satisfies the constraints of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

---

**Edit: After much fiddling around I've come to the conclusion this is much harder to solve in general using the strategy described below than I initially thought.**

**The problem is that, particularly when all the registers are used, there is nothing to stop the first register stash from overwriting another. Whether there is some trick to play with using direct memory writes that can be optimised away I don't know, but initial tests would suggest the compiler might still choose to clobber not-yet-stashed registers**

**For the time being and until I have more information, I'm unmarking this answer as correct and this answer should treated as probably wrong in the general case. My conclusion is this that such local protection of registers needs better support in the compiler to be useful**

---

This absolutely is possible to do reliably. Drawing on the comments by @PeterCordes as well as the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) and a couple of useful bug reports (gcc [41538](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41538) and [37188](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37188)) I came up with the following solution.

The point that makes it valid is the use of temporary variables to make sure the registers are maintained (logically, if the loop clobbers them, then they will be reloaded). In practice, the temporary variables are optimised away which is clear from inspection of the resultant asm.

```
// d0 and d1 map to the first and second values of q0, so we use
// q0 to reduce the number of tmp variables we pass around (instead
// of using one for each of d0 and d1).
register float32x4_t data __asm__ ("q0");
register float32x4_t output __asm__ ("q12");

float32x4_t tmp_data;
float32x4_t tmp_output;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "vldmia.64 %[data_addr]!, {d0-d1}\n\t"
        "vmov.f32 %q[output], #0.0\n\t"
        : [data_addr] "+r" (data_addr),
        [output] "=&w" (output),
        "=&w" (data) // we still need to constrain data (q0) as written to.
        ::);

// Stash the register values
tmp_data = data;
tmp_output = output;

for(int n=0; n<10; ++n){

    // Make sure the registers are loaded correctly
    output = tmp_output;
    data = tmp_data;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "vadd.f32 %[output], %[output], q0\n\t"
            "vldmia.64 %[data_addr]!, {d0-d1}\n\t"
            : [data_addr] "+r" (data_addr),
            [output] "+w" (output),
            "+w" (data) // again, data (q0) was written to in the vldmia op.
            ::);

    // Remember to stash the registers again before continuing
    tmp_data = data;
    tmp_output = output;
}
```

It's necessary to instruct the compiler that `q0` is written to in the last line of each asm output constraint block, so it doesn't think it can reorder the stashing and reloading of the `data` register resulting in the asm block getting invalid values.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `tmp` stuff?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee the register won't be clobbered as specified by the docs.

Comment: Yeah you seem to be right. I will delete the comment to avoid confusion. But also note that if you don't particularly care about using `q0` or `q12` you could just let the compiler pick a register and so you wouldn't need the `tmp` :)

Comment: Except there seems to be no constraint for a `q` register. So much for that theory.

Comment: Very nice. I thought something like this might have been possible after Peter's comment, but got caught up with $realwork. You should accept this as the answer; I don't need more karma for being wrong.